# How to get Bitmap id from ImageView in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have an `ImageView` and I am setting different image based on different condition like this way-

```
if(x==1){
    image.setImageResource(bitMapIdOne);
}else {
    image.setImageResource(bitMapIdTwo);
}
```

Now I want to get the `id` of `Bitmap` from this `ImageView`. I want to get `id` like this way `image.getId()` that will return currently set Bitmap id. Suppose that current id is `bitMapIdOne` and it will return `bitMapIdOne` for me.

Is it possible or how do I get `Bitmap` id?

Comment: a bitmap doesnt have an id, so you wont be able to get the id from it, you will have to save the current id somewhere so you keep track of the images id, the view wont do that work for you

Comment: no,  you can't do this,  try ImageView.getDrawable() instead

Comment: Create a method, getBitmapForX(int x) which returns the bitmap depending on the value of x?

Comment: Everytime that you do a image.setImageResource(id) also do a image.setTag(id). Then you can retrieve the id with id=(int)image.getTag();

Answer (score 0):

a bitmap does not have id. You are needed to use **setImageBitmap** instead of **setImageResource**

Answer (score 0):

You can the ImageView's drawable, the app's drawables and find out which one is it by comparison:

```
if (image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1).getConstantState())) {

} else if (image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2).getConstantState()) {

}
```